# getting wrong android google play Install Referrer

Tags: android, performance, google-analytics, google-play, broadcastreceiver

I have successfully setup install referrer in my android application.Also, I am getting the proper referrer in the application from play store when user install it.(The application is live and working fine with referrer.)
Now, The problem is when I checked my database I got some of the referrers like

> utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_term=

Whereas, this is not my referrer code which i have shared. 
I am not able to find a source for these referrers that my app is getting.

Comment: must be the organic downloads?

Answer (score 0):

Your question may have already been answered by now, but for the benefit for those who may stumble upon this question, these values are received when a user goes installs directly from google play without following any link. At least, that is what i can deduce based on previous experiences.